# Postgres: Subquery with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to optimize a query (instead of repeating it a lot of time), with this **NOT FUNCTIONAL CODE** above (since subqueries only return 1 column):

```sql
SELECT
    e.pageview_identifier,
    e.created_at,
    e.pageview_current_url,
    e.pageview_mobile,
    (
        SELECT event_type, COUNT(event_identifier)
        FROM events v
        WHERE
            v.company_identifier = e.company_identifier AND
            v.user_identifier = e.user_identifier AND
            v.pageview_identifier = e.pageview_identifier
        GROUP BY v.event_type
    )
FROM events e
WHERE
    company_identifier = 'xyz' AND
    user_identifier = '01CDQZVSJFBDA8W444JS2CS3BA' AND
    event_type = 'page:view';
```

Basically, I want to retrieve the columns as

```
pageview_identifier, created_at, ..., event_type_a_count, event_type_b_count, ...
```

A **FUNCTIONAL** code that works is:

```
SELECT
    e.pageview_identifier,
    e.created_at,
    e.pageview_current_url,
    e.pageview_mobile,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(event_identifier)
        FROM events v
        WHERE
            v.company_identifier = e.company_identifier AND
            v.user_identifier = e.user_identifier AND
            v.pageview_identifier = e.pageview_identifier AND
            v.event_type = 'mouse:move'
    ) as mouse_move_count
FROM events e
WHERE
    company_identifier = 'xyz' AND
    user_identifier = '01CDQZVSJFBDA8W444JS2CS3BA' AND
    event_type = 'page:view';
```

But in this case, I would need to repeat a lot of time this subquery for each kind of `event_type`.

Edit 1 - More information:

On my `WHERE` clause, I restrict it to only `event_type = 'page:view'`. I have some possible values for `event_type`, and for each `page:view`, I need to count related events (with different `event_type`) to it based on the condition `e.pageview_identifier = v.pageview_identifier`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a window function:

```
    SELECT e.pageview_identifier,
           e.created_at,
           e.pageview_current_url,
           e.pageview_mobile,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.company_identifier, e.user_identifier, e.pageview_identifier) as cnt
    FROM events e
    WHERE e.company_identifier = 'xyz' AND
          e.user_identifier = '01CDQZVSJFBDA8W444JS2CS3BA' AND
          e.event_type = 'page:view';
```

Note:  This counts only `'page:view'` events.  If you want a count of each event, then one way is:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.pageview_identifier,
             e.created_at,
             e.pageview_current_url,
             e.pageview_mobile,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE .event_type = 'mouse:move') OVER (PARTITION BY e.company_identifier, e.user_identifier, e.pageview_identifier) as cnt_mouse_move,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE .event_type = ''page:view'') OVER (PARTITION BY e.company_identifier, e.user_identifier, e.pageview_identifier) as cnt_page_view,
             . . .
      FROM events e
      WHERE e.company_identifier = 'xyz' AND
          e.user_identifier = '01CDQZVSJFBDA8W444JS2CS3BA' 
     ) e
WHERE e.event_type = 'page:view';
```

Comment: On my `WHERE` clause, I restrict it to only `event_type = 'page:view'`. I have some possible values for `event_type`, and for each `page:view`, I need to count related events to it based on the condition `e.pageview_identifier = v.pageview_identifier`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I tried to upvote and set as an Accepted Answer, but I don't have enough reputation and I need to wait 5min before accept it.